# print lines that have similar columns with multiple delimiters

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have two files:

file1.txt

```
dn_id101_400_CT_TC    string1
dn_id111_60_TT_AA    string2
```

file2.txt

```
dn_id101_400_XX_XX    diffstring1
dn_id400_40_XY_YX    diffstring2
dn_id111_60_GG_CC    diffstring3
```

I want to print the lines from file2.txt if the first three elements separated by `_` from file1.txt are present in the line in file2.txt. Here is my desired output:

```
dn_id101_400_XX_XX    diffstring1
dn_id111_60_GG_CC    diffstring3
```

Is there a way to to do this? Maybe by changing the delimiter of an `awk`? I'm not sure how to handle multiple delimiters in an `awk` command. Here's an example of what I'd like to use:

```
awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; $1 in a' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '     
            {s=$1; sub(/_[[:upper:]]+_[[:upper:]]+$/, "", s)} 
    FNR==NR { arr[s]++} 
    FNR<NR && (s in arr)' f1 f2
dn_id101_400_XX_XX  diffstring1
dn_id111_60_GG_CC   diffstring3
```

That assumes that `/_[[:upper:]]+_[[:upper:]]+$/` correctly describes the part you need to remove to make the data keys overlap between the two files.

If you want to go left to right (irrespective of the number of `_` after the first three) use `split` instead:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '     
            { split($1, a, /_/); s=a[1]"_"a[2]"_"a[3]} 
    FNR==NR { arr[s]++} 
    FNR<NR && (s in arr)' f1 f2
```

Comment: Thank you @dawg! I was able to easily edit the second solution to fit my specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

alternative solution with `cut`, `paste`, `join`, `sort` and function definition to replicate `awk` functionality

```
$ f() { paste <(cut -d_ -f1-3 ${1}) ${1} | sort; }; \
  join -o2.2,2.3 <(f file1) <(f file2)    

dn_id101_400_XX_XX diffstring1
dn_id111_60_GG_CC diffstring3
```

create the key and sort for join, pick columns to output, defining function is for eliminate duplicated code.

Comment: This would probably work well. However, I've been having some serious problems with getting my `join` in general to work appropriately. Thank you for your suggestion! :)

Comment: what is not working? other than output formatting there is no hidden magic in `join`, uses default key.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
$ awk -F_ '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3} NR==FNR{a[k];next} k in a' file1 file2
dn_id101_400_XX_XX    diffstring1
dn_id111_60_GG_CC    diffstring3
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to pull out the "key" value that your want from file1.

```
awk -F_ '
        NR==FNR{str="^"$1"_"$2"_"$3; arr[str]=str}
        NR!=FNR{for (x in arr){if ($0 ~ x) {print  $0 ; next }}}
        #END{for(x in arr) print "arr["x"]="arr[x]}
        ' f1.txt f2.txt
```

**output**

```
dn_id101_400_XX_XX    diffstring1
dn_id111_60_GG_CC    diffstring3
```

This reconstructs the first 3 `_` separated values from file1 as `$1"_"$2"_"$3`.
Remove the `#` comment char to see what values are stored in `arr[]`.

The `NR==FNR` and `NR!=FNR` control which file is read into `arr[]` and which is processed to match with `($0 ~ str)`.

IHTH

Comment: You might want to anchor the regex match to start of string and also break out of the loop in case speed is an issue.

Comment: @shawnt00 : Yes, thanks for the good ideas. Updated my answer, although EdM beats me in the # of chars reduction department! ;-) Good luck to all.